# Over riding eclipse with TabHost error

Tags: android, overriding, android-tabhost

I currently have this error that I believe to be a fault in eclipse:

```
Error during post inflation process:
TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs".
View found with id 'tabs' is 'com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView'

The following classes could not be found:
- TabWidget
```

This is apparently a problem with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/bkgrnd">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/quizicon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ImageView>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:textSize="@dimen/menuTitleSize"
                android:text="@string/scores"></TextView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/quizicon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ImageView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TabWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/tabs"></TabWidget>
                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
                    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout_AllScores"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:stretch_columns="*"></TableLayout>
                    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout_FriendScores"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:stretch_columns="*"></TableLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Since this is an error with eclipse, and the code is actually correct, is there a way to override the error so it'll let me compile.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a great answer but eclipse at times has listed non-existent errors for me, after exhaustive debugging if I cant find the answer I have resolved by deleting the error from the error list and cleaning the project, then build the project.

Ronan